# Behavior of select() on stdin when used on a pipe

Tags: select, pipe, stdin

I am trying to understand an observation on behavior of select() when used on stdin, when it is receiving data from a pipe.

Basically I had a simple C program using the following code:
hello.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int flags, opt;
  int nsecs, tfnd;
  fd_set rfds;
  struct timeval tv;
  int retval;
  int stdin_fileno_p1 = STDIN_FILENO+1;
  char c;
  int n;

  /* Turn off canonical processing on stdin*/
  static struct termios oldt, newt;
  tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
  newt = oldt;
  newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);
  tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);

  while (1)
  {
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &rfds);
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    retval = select(stdin_fileno_p1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if ( retval && (retval!=-1) )
    {
      n = read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);
      write(STDOUT_FILENO, &c, 1);
    }
    else printf("No Data\n");
    usleep(100000);
  }
  tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
}
```

If I ran the program as follows I could see characters echoing when I type keys on while the program is running. When keys are not pressed, it displays "No Data" as expected.

```
./hello
```

However, if use the program as follows, the program never gets to a state where is displays "No Data". Instead last character "c" is repeatedly displayed.

```
echo -n abc | ./hello
```

I'm a bit puzzled by this observation, and would be grateful if you could help me to understand the observed behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your program does not detect an end-of-file condition when it reads from the `STDIN_FILENO` descriptor.  After `echo` has written the `c` character it will close its end of the pipe, which will cause the  `select` in your program to return immediately and your `read` to return 0 as an indication that no more data will ever be available from that descriptor.  Your program doesn't detect that condition.  Instead it just calls `write` with whatever character was left in the buffer by the last successful `read` and then repeats the loop.

To fix, do `if (n==0) break;` after the `read`.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense. Does this also mean that select() will not return error condition (-1) when the fd refer to a closed file?

Comment: `select` will return -1 if any of the descriptors refers to a closed file.  That doesn't happen in your program because you never close your program's STDIN descriptor.  If you `close(STDIN_FILENO)` when `read` returns 0 and you stay in the loop, then you will see a -1 from the next `select` call.  (The `close` performed on the writing end of the pipe in the `echo` program does not close the reading end of the pipe in your program.  It only causes an 'end of file' indication for the `read` in your program.)